# How to get comma separated list without calling AsEnumerable()

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm coding a Linq query and it's about 16000 records and one parameter is a list that is converted to comma separated string.
I know I can call `AsEnumerable` and then use the `string.Join` statement but I want to do this before the query goes into memory so that it will be faster.

```
//I know that this does not compile to SQL and will give an error. 
//But I was wondering if there is another way to convert a List to comma seperated string like this
    
    var test = (from t in Testtable
                where t.id = 1
                select string.Join(",", t.TestVariable)).ToList()     
    
    //I don't want to have to do this
    
    var test = (from t in Testtable
                    where t.id = 1
                    select t).ToList().Select(x => string.Join(",", x.TestVariable))
```

Comment: Why don't  you want to do this on the client?  In this case the individual values is going to be about the same, if not even *less* data going over the wire than the combined string, and the DB isn't in any better position to do the string processing than the client (it's not like you're taking advantages of indexes or anything to perform the operation any more efficiently).  If anything doing this work on the client is preferable because they tend to scale better than DBs.

Comment: None of your code will work. Perhaps try expressing it in SQL first to understand the issues?

Comment: @NetMage They question itself acknowledges that the first one doesn't work.  That's what they want to be able to do.  The second one would work just fine.  So I don't understand your comment.  And joining strings *is* something SQL (or at least some DB providers) can do (although this code doesn't make it do that).

Comment: @Servy a `(` seems to be missing, though. But let's write that off as a typo.

Comment: @Fildor Okay, sure, but that' doesn't really detract from the point of the question.  Just a typo.  If that was NetMage's point they should have just edited it in rather than commenting.

Comment: @Servy Absolutely agree.

Comment: If you have a two dimensional object this may wsork :var test = Testtable.Where(t => t.id == 1).SelectMany(t => t.Select(u => string.Join(",", u.TestVariable))).ToList()

Comment: @Servy What is `t.TestVariable`? What is `Select(x = `?

Comment: @NetMage An ienumerable  and a typo.

Comment: Sorry guys, I wrote that code in a hurry so it was missing a few things. I changed it. 
@Servy I'll try to run it on client and see how slow it is.

Comment: Put in a comment to make it more clear what I was asking about.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
var test = string.Join(",", (from t in Testtable
                                         where t.id = 1
                                         select t.TestVariable as string));
```

or

```
var test = string.Join(",", (from t in Testtable
                                             where t.id = 1
                                             select t.TestVariable ));
```

also if you want to use less memories you can use IQueryable. I mean that run query (with conditions) in database after that use Linq query

Comment: his just doesn't even produce the proper results, in addition to not doing the concatenation on the DB as the question asks. The second example in the question is working code. They clearly want a sequences of CSV strings, not a single giant string (such a string is likely to result in OOM errors even).

Comment: @yusif This would work but in my example I have a let statement and string.Join wont compile from linq to SQL

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
var test = string.Join(",", (from t in Testtable
    where t.id = 1
    select t.testVar));
```

Comment: This just doesn't even produce the proper results, in addition to not doing the concatenation on the DB as the question asks.  The second example in the question is working code.  They clearly want a sequences of CSV strings, not a single giant string (such a string is likely to result in OOM errors even).

Comment: @Servy I appreciate the feedback. I think I did misunderstand the question. I would be curious to see your answer to the question posted as an answer. Thank you

Comment: As stated in my original comment, there's no *need* to perform this operation on the DB in the first place  Doing so would be rather difficult and would add a lot of complexity to the code without adding value, so I would merely advice the OP to simply use their existing working code and not change it.